# Error while importing sql in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, import, phpmyadmin

While I'm trying to import a .sql backup in phpmyadmin , I get this error :

****Error**

SQL query:

```
--
-- Dumping data for table `wp_commentmeta`
--
INSERT INTO `wp_commentmeta` ( `meta_id` , `comment_id` , `meta_key` , `meta_value` )

VALUES ( 2, 2, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0' ) , ( 3, 2, '_wp_trash_meta_time', '1398086942' ) ;
```

MySQL said:

> 1062 - Duplicate entry '2' for key 'PRIMARY'**

What should I do?

Comment: The schema is not compatible to the data. You could disable constraint checks, however the application might not work as expected afterwards. There is no general answer to that problem, however if you have duplicate data, remove it first. E.g. truncate the tables first.

Comment: You should understand the basics of mysql **what is primary key? . ** you cant duplicate the data with the same primary key. Check your table structure . And your data

Answer (score 0):

1. You cant duplicate the data with the same primary key
2. Truncate your current table and try it again (TRUNCATE your_table;)

   OR DELETE FROM your_table WHERE your_ID_field LIKE 2
3. **IF** your ID field is **AUTO_INCREMENT** field you can slove it like this

   ```
   INSERT INTO `wp_commentmeta` ( `meta_key` , `meta_value` )

   VALUES ('_wp_trash_meta_status', '0' ),
          ('_wp_trash_meta_time', '1398086942' ) ;
   ```